# table with horizontal scroll wont extend to end of headers

Tags: html, css

I have a simple html table where i am trying to get the body to extend to the end of the headers/table. I need it to have horizontal scroll only for the body and have fixed headers.

I have a fiddle here that shows the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZbdZe/54/

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
<thead >
<tr>
<th  id="th1"  width="50%">first</th>
<th  id="th2" width="50%" >last</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody style="display: block; border: 1px solid green; height: 530px; overflow-y: scroll">
<tr>
<td headers="th1" >Hello</td>
<td headers="th2" >World</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Right now it extendes only the first heading. I need it to extend the full width of the table with scroll. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is to have fixed table header created by another table

Second table for the body of the table with scroll

```css
table{
  border-collapse:collapse;
  width:100%
}
tbody{
   border: 1px solid green;
   table-layout: fixed;
}
div{
  height: 66px; /*adjust table body*/
  overflow-y: scroll
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th  id="th1" width="39%">first</th>
      <th  id="th2" width="50%" >last</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<div>

<table border=1>
<tbody>
  <tr>  
    <td headers="th1" >Hello</td>
    <td headers="th2" >World</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td headers="th1" >Hello</td>
    <td headers="th2" >World</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td headers="th1" >Hello</td>
    <td headers="th2" >World</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td headers="th1" >Hello</td>
    <td headers="th2" >World</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</div>
```